# Rails turbolinks:load event fires but corresponding function does not

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I am developing a Rails Gem and part of it's functionality injects a javascript tracking code into the HTML body of a rails view/page.

However, Turbolinks is giving me an issue. My tracking code script runs fine on pages with full page refreshes but for pages that don't, the script doesn't run (although I can see it present in the body of the HTML)

Without Turbolinks, everything works fine but I know a lot of people use it so want to find a solution to work with it (so Jquery.turbolinks gem is not really a solution)

Here is what I have tried so far. (I've consoled logged the statement 'working?' to see if the turbolinks:load event is actually firing on the pages I expect it to, and it is. So now just unsure why the script 'trackingCode' function won't fire either.)

```
var trackingCode;

trackingCode = function() {

  // my javascript code

};

$(document).ready(trackingCode)
$(document).on('page:load', trackingCode)
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', trackingCode);
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', console.log('working?'))
```

Hopefully that is clear enough but please let me know if there's anymore information needed.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just make the function part of the call, instead of being off on its own? `$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() { ... });`

Comment: thank you, i have tried that but it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'ready'.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    console.log('it works');
});
```

Or for turbolinks-classic

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
    console.log('it works');
});
```